# Angular Updates Model but no Two Way Binding w/ Custom Filter

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-filters

I recently wrote a simple custom filter which only displays items in my model given a specific model property and it works great. It is below..

### Filter

```
app.filter('status', function() {
    return function(input, theStatus) {
        var out = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            var widget = input[i];
            if (widget.status === theStatus)
                out.push(widget);
        }

        return out;
    };
});
```

The filter is applied as such on an `ng-repeat`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="widget in pendingWidgets = (widgetList | status: 0)">
    <td><a href="" ng-click="updateStatus(widget.widgetId, 1)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="" ng-click="updateStatus(widget.widgetId, 2)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="" ng-click="updateStatus(widget.widgetId, 3)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="" ng-click="updateStatus(widget.widgetId, 4)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

And on a panel heading as so

```
<div class="panel-heading"><span class="badge">{{pendingWidgets.length}}</span></div>
```

When the glyph is clicked `ng-click` runs `updateStatus()` as below...

```
$scope.updateStatus = function(theId, newStatus) {
    widgets.setStatus(tagNumber, newStatus);
    $scope.displayAlert = true;
};
```

And the  `widget.setStatus()` is as such..

```
app.factory('widgets', ['$http', function($http) {
    var o = {
        widgets:[]
    };

    o.setStatus = function(aWidget, theStatus) {
        return $http.put('/widgets/' + aWidget, { 'status': theStatus }).success(function (data) {
            // do I need to put something here?
        });
    };

    return o;
}]);
```

My question lies in

> How can I get my page to refresh on the `ng-click` action when the updateStatus() call is made on my model? When the glyph is clicked the model is updated but the page is not. Only on a page refresh or when I visit a different page and then come back does the page display the updated model accurately with respect to the custom filter.

Comment: You send the new status to the server, but I can't see where you set the status of the model object itself. I would expect something like `o.status = theStatus` in your `o.setStatus()` function

Comment: My mistake. I forgot to add the rest of my `factory`. It's set in the o.setStatus() function inside my app factory with the $http.put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're updating the status for a particular widget (on the client side). You're telling your server about the update, but on the client side, no update happens.

That's why when you refresh (i imagine you're loading the widgets from the db / backend) you see the update.

Where you have: `// do I need to put something here?` you need to do something like:

`aWidget.status = data.status; // where data is the updated widget object`

*(this assumes that your backend is returning the updated widget - which if you're following the same conventions that I'm used to - it should be).*

Comment: My mistake. I forgot to add the rest of my `factory`. It's set in the o.setStatus() function inside my app factory with the $http.put.

Comment: Can you show me how its being set? `o.setStatus()` seems to only make an `$http.put` request - but never actually updates the client side object.

Comment: `$http.put('/widgets/' + aWidget, { 'status': theStatus });` this updates the model. I see what you're saying in your answer. I tried adding `aWidget.status = theStatus` into the `.success()` call back but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: aWidget is an ID, not the object itself

Comment: You're right! I forgot! So given that this is in the factory, I would do what @keithm said in his comment above.

Comment: Well the down side to doing that outside the .success is if a failure occurs - then your view is now inaccurate. But maybe you can handle that elsewhere or maybe you don't care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92090/discussion-between-gh0st-and-kevin-friedheim).